# Logout Paypal Express account after payment is completed

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I want to logout paypal account when the payment is completed in Paypal.
retun url in expresscheckout takes to website and payment is done .But Paypal account still not logout.
How do i acheve this ?

Just try this with your Paypal account. If you forgot to log out from your Paypal account after finishing using it and just close the window without log off from the computer you were using. Then, next person using the same computer can simply enter your Paypal account and do whatever they want!

Is there any way to logout Paypal account when payment is completed.so that if u forget to logout the system it will be be done automatically.. so that no one cam misuse it..

Answer (score 1):

the only way to do this is grab the logOut URL and use this as your redirect URL; this will auto close after the customer completes the payment automatically 8^).

So for sandbox it would be:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_logout and for the live URL, as mentioned above grab your logout URL from your own paypal account and use that for the return.

Comment: I'm not sure why as I've tested this several times and it works. Where are you grabbing the URL and what are you getting on the return?

Comment: Should you use this URL with PayPal Express Checkout.