# PayPal Checkout - Create a Logout link

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on integrating PayPal Checkout into a new shopping cart and everything is working fine on the payment end. Once the user has logged in I place a custom welcome message on the page: 
[Custom welcome message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCr5C.png)

I'd like to allow the customer to logout from PayPal directly from the cart (a la Amazon) without having to get back into the PayPal popup to use their (sometimes missing) 'Not you?' link.

The issue is what URL or method should the click trigger? I've been unable to find any reference to a logout method in the Checkout docs and examples.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I have tried using the URL directly off of the 'Not you?' link inside the popup to no avail. Inspecting that element it looks to be using Angular to trigger the logout:
  `ng-click='actions.logout()'`
  I'm not at all familiar with Angular, so am unsure if this is something I can work with and hook into using jQuery or vanilla JS.
- Came across this question on SO -
  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873040/logout-paypal-express-account-after-payment-is-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873040/logout-paypal-express-account-after-payment-is-completed/39089771#39089771) - but the URL does not log the user out (maybe I'm missing some required params?)
- I cannot simply remove the PayPal cookie to wipe the session since the cookie belongs to the paypal domain and not my domain.

I'm using PayPal's checkout.js version 4.0.172

If anyone has experience with a similar task or can make any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.